# Pidgin XMPP chat not decoding HTML.

Tags: html, pidgin, chat, xmpp

Right now in Pidgin chat, we have a Github bot that posts when things get updated, including links.

However, for whatever reason those messages come in as HTML instead of whatever pidgin uses.

Is there anyway to make pidgin decode that html?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on Pidgin, but I do know LOTS about XMPP. in short, XMPP only supports a subset of XHTML, and "rich" content delivered over XMPP to <-> from pidgin is likely to be of this limited XHTML subset. Have a look at [XEP-0071: XHTML-IM](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0071.html). This is about as much as I can suggest without being able to see the raw (full) XMPP message stanzas. If I were to hazard a guess, I would think that you aren't properly formatting your messages with the proper wrapper elements:

> **5. Wrapper Element**
>
> The root element for including XHTML content within XMPP stanzas is <html/>. This element is qualified by the 'http://jabber.org/protocol/xhtml-im' namespace. From the perspective of XMPP, the wrapper element functions as an XMPP extension element; from the perspective of XHTML, it functions as a wrapper for XHTML 1.0 content qualified by the 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' namespace. Such XHTML content MUST be contained in one or more  elements qualified by the 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' namespace and MUST conform to the XHTML-IM Integration Set defined in the following section. If more than one  element is included in the  wrapper element, each  element MUST possess an 'xml:lang' attribute with a distinct value, where the value of that attribute MUST adhere to the rules defined in RFC 5646 [18]. A formal definition of the  element is provided in the XHTML-IM Wrapper Schema.